# Looking for ways to transform time-series data recorded from object movement into equation describing the movement direction of the object

Tags: algorithms, linear-transformations, machine-learning, time-series

Looking for some **time-series data transformation** advice!

I want to know what's the best way to transform **data of 9-tuples time series data** of IMU (Inertia Measurement Unit) sensor, recorded from a pen drawing a straight line in 2D space into **the equation that describes the direction of the pen**.

Basically I'm looking for a **function/algorithm that maps a 9-axes time-series data into a linear combination in the form of aX + bY + cZ**, in order to know which direction the pen is moving on a 2D plane (c = 0). **Note that I can label all data**, hence a supervised algorithm is possible, but not necessary.

The IMU data are 9-tuple time-series data in the form of:

- 3 axes of linear acceleration (collected from the accelerometer)
- 3 axes of angular velocity (collected from the gyroscope)
- 3 axes of magnetic field strength (collected from the magnetometer)

Any tip or advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks ahead!